# Android past time relative to now, in milliseconds

Tags: java, android, time

How would I continuously calculate time relative to now in milliseconds.

I want to be able to get these moments in time relative to the current time.
So if i have a method hooked to a button and everytime I pressed it would
return the millisecond representation of the below:

```
  5 mins ago = ?
  15 mins ago =  ? 
  30 mins ago =
  a day ago
  a week ago
```

I'm pretty confused with all the material out there on dates and such.

Can anyone dumb it down, using Android/Java methodologies.

Comment: thanks to ev1 for the answers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[System.currentTimeinMilis](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29) returns the current time in milliseconds. and you can easily find out the millisecond for the intervals (i.e. 5, 15 30 min .. etc ). so subtract two values and you will get the result.

In order to get milliseconds value you can use [`TimeUnit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html):

```
long fiveMinutesInMillis = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(5);
```

Comment: thanks... beat me too it. thought it out! thank you for your time though.

Comment: I would also suggest using `TimeUnit` to get milliseconds: `TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(5)`

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
 private static final int SECOND_MILLIS = 1000;
private static final int MINUTE_MILLIS = 60 * SECOND_MILLIS;
private static final int HOUR_MILLIS = 60 * MINUTE_MILLIS;
private static final int DAY_MILLIS = 24 * HOUR_MILLIS;

  public static String getTimeAgo(long time, Context ctx) {
    if (time < 1000000000000L) {
        // if timestamp given in seconds, convert to millis
        time *= 1000;
    }

    long now = getCurrentTime(ctx);
    if (time > now || time <= 0) {
        return "just now";
    }

    // TODO: localize
    final long diff = now - time;
    if (diff < MINUTE_MILLIS) {
        return "just now";
    } else if (diff < 2 * MINUTE_MILLIS) {
        return "a min ago";
    } else if (diff < 50 * MINUTE_MILLIS) {
        return diff / MINUTE_MILLIS + " mins ago";
    } else if (diff < 90 * MINUTE_MILLIS) {
        return "an hr ago";
    } else if (diff < 24 * HOUR_MILLIS) {
        return diff / HOUR_MILLIS + " hrs ago";
    } else if (diff < 48 * HOUR_MILLIS) {
        return "yesterday";
    } else {
        return diff / DAY_MILLIS + " days ago";
    }
}
```

Comment: (A) Joda-Time has classes built and debugged for this work of describing a span of time as years, months, etc. Silly to do this on your own. (B) The question seems to be simpler, just wanted milliseconds between two date-times.

Answer (score 0):

GregorianCalendar c1 = new GregorianCalendar(currentYear, currentMonth, currentDay);
long l1 = c1.getTimeInMillis();